# PostgreSQL: Count items created before a time range in a series

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, date-range

## Description

Consider the following table in a [PostgreSQL 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1481/) database:

```
                                        Table "public.users"
       Column       |           Type           |                      Modifiers
--------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 sid                | bigint                   | not null default nextval('users_sid_seq'::regclass)
 creation_time      | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 ...
```

I would like to generate a report of the amount of users created prior to a timestamp, for a range of timestamps, which should look like:

```
    sampling_time    |   number_of_users |
---------------------+-------------------+
 2014-11-01 00:00:00 |   100             |
 2014-11-02 00:00:00 |   105             |
 2014-11-03 00:00:00 |   110             |
 2014-11-04 00:00:00 |   120             |
 2014-11-05 00:00:00 |   125             |
 2014-11-06 00:00:00 |   150             |
 2014-11-07 00:00:00 |   201             |
 2014-11-08 00:00:00 |   100             |
 2014-11-09 00:00:00 |   250             |
 2014-11-10 00:00:00 |   300             |
 2014-11-11 00:00:00 |   400             |
```

## What I've tried

Generating the timestamp series is easy using `generate_series`:

```
SELECT generate_series('2014-11-01'::timestamp, 
                       '2014-11-11'::timestamp, 
                       '1 day'::interval) AS sampling_time
```

### Query

Trying to combine the series and the `COUNT(*)` on users fail:

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT generate_series('2014-11-01'::timestamp, 
                        '2014-11-11'::timestamp, 
                        '1 day'::interval)) AS sampling_time,

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM users 
        WHERE creation_time<=sampling_time) 
AS created_before_sampling_time;
```

### Error message

```
ERROR:  column "sampling_time" does not exist
LINE 7:             WHERE creation_time<=sampling_time)
```

Any idea how to sub-query the count on users depending on the `samping_time` of each row?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) instead.

```
SELECT
  sampling_time.date,
  SUM(COUNT(u.*)) OVER (ORDER BY sampling_time.date) AS number_of_users
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    (SELECT MIN(creation_time::date) FROM users),
    CURRENT_DATE,
    '1 day'::interval
  ) sampling_time LEFT JOIN users
ON
  u.creation_time::date = sampling_time.date
GROUP BY
  sampling_time.date;
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that technique.

Comment: However, I would like to have the total number of users registered before that point in time, not the window. Any idea how to change your query to do that?

Comment: How do you mean *before that point in time*? The part `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE creation_time < '2014-11-01')` is exactly for that purpose - to add all the users added before that date.

Comment: But, at least in my execution, there is a lower bound limit too. I would like to list the number of users created from the dawn of time to that point in time.

Comment: Well you can get rid of the `generate_series()` altogether with the abovementioned `count()` and simply select directly from users without any date condition in the where clause.

Comment: Or, if you want a continuos set of dates, then use `MIN(creation_time)` (a.k.a. *the dawn of time*) as the first agrument for `generate_series()`. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:-

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT generate_series('2014-11-01'::timestamp, 
                    '2014-11-11'::timestamp, 
                    '1 day'::interval)) AS sampling_time, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM users 
 WHERE creation_time<=sampling_time)AS created_before_sampling_time);
```

I think there must be some parenthesis errors in your syntax.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a simple solution, but I get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 4:'1 day'::interval)) AS sampling_time,`